# register_shutdown_function() not called?

Tags: php

```
<?php
register_shutdown_function("myerror");
function myerror(){
echo "here";
}
function test(){}
function test(){}
```

In this condition，register_shutdown_function() not called，why?

Comment: mind posting actual code, rather than an image of? *grazie*. I mean surely, it would have taken less time posting actual code than a screenshot.

Comment: ^ you see the amounts of upvotes it received? That's a message in its own right. **Paste your code**. Your question will continue to get downvoted and voted to close until you do. You don't expect us to retype that for you, do you? *Wish*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I will paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`register_shutdown_function` doesn't get invoked for errors raised during the parsing stage, such as redeclaring the same function. It's called on script *shutdown*, which doesn't happen if your script didn't execute in the first place.

Compare your code to

```
<?php
register_shutdown_function(function () { echo PHP_EOL, 'Script has shut down'; });

function foo() {}
if (true) { function foo() {} }
```

Here, the function is only re-declared at run-time, so the shutdown function is called:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare foo() (previously declared in /tmp/execpad-914847fcd3fa/source-914847fcd3fa:4) in /tmp/execpad-914847fcd3fa/source-914847fcd3fa on line 5
>
> **Script has shut down**

Comment: if (true) {
   echo 1
}

Comment: yeah，but
if (true) {
   echo 1
}
this condition not called the function.